# How can I have both real counts and grouped percentages in mij bar chart?

Tags: r, ggplot2, geom-bar

I have this df [hulp_def_GE_lang.R or .xlsx](https://github.com/Marlein/Tim.git) in which the choices are mentioned where 247 participants gave there ideas on what green energy is. They could choose from several options, so some participants (identified bij 'Number') had checked a lot of boxes(choices) and some just a few.

I want a bar chart like this:
[image]

My problem is, that the percentages are based on the number of participants and NOT on the number of total of choices.

I made the bar chart so far like this:[image]

with this code:

```
hulp_def_GE_lang %>%
  drop_na(Choice_short) %>%
  ggplot(aes(fct_rev(fct_infreq(Choice_short)))) +
  geom_bar(fill = "pink") +
  geom_text(stat='count', aes(label=..count..), hjust=0) +
  ylim(0,280) +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 330, hjust = 0)) +
  labs(x = "Wat is groene energie?",
       y = "Aantal keren gekozen") +
  coord_flip()
```

The percentages should be calculated based upon the number of participants, where all NA's are excluded. So I have 244 participants:

[image]

I cannot find a solution to base the percentages calculation on the total number of groups of the variable 'Numbers'.

Answer (score 1):

You can perform the calculation first before plotting.

To calculate the percentages, count the number of rows for each value in `Choice_short` and divide it by number of unique values of `Number`.

```
library(tidyverse)

hulp_def_GE_lang %>%
  drop_na(Choice_short) %>%
  group_by(Choice_short) %>%
  summarise(n = n(), 
            label = sprintf('%d (%.2f%%)', n, n/n_distinct(.$Number) * 100)) %>%
  arrange(n) %>%
  mutate(Choice_short = factor(Choice_short, Choice_short)) %>%
  ggplot(aes(Choice_short, n)) +
  geom_col(fill = "pink") +
  geom_text(aes(label= label), hjust=0) +
  ylim(0,280) +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 330, hjust = 0)) +
  labs(x = "Wat is groene energie?",
       y = "Aantal keren gekozen") +
  coord_flip()
```

[image]